# Searching for public folder in routes path

Tags: node.js, express

Whenever a different route is visited other than the root, express is not able to find the public folder containing all the stylesheets and javascript files, instead it searches for the assets inside the route path.
Any help would be appreciated.

**error**
when visiting *http://localhost:3000/users/login/* gives -

GET /users/login/stylesheets/bootstrap.css 404 14.872 ms - 10418
GET /users/login/stylesheets/style.css 404 7.134 ms - 10418
GET /users/login/javascripts/bootstrap.js 404 57.890 ms - 10418
GET /users/login/javascripts/bootstrap.js 404 5.326 ms - 10418

**app.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();

// extra modules
var hbs = require('hbs');
var defaultLogger = require('express-logger');

var index = require('./routes/index');
var users = require('./routes/users');

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'hbs');
app.set('view options', {layout: './layouts/application'});
hbs.registerPartials(__dirname + '/views/layouts/partials');

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(defaultLogger({path: "log/development.log"})); //logger
app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'bulb.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/', index);
app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

**uses.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var userService = require('../services/users')

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  userService.all(function(users){
    res.render('users/dummy')
  })
});

// GET login form
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next){
  res.render('users/login', {title: 'Login'});
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Can you provide the parts of the HTML where the styles and scripts are loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess your path now in this format:

`<link href="stylesheets/bootstrap.css">`

You should always contain `/` at the start of the path. This will help you to load the correct path.

`<link href="/stylesheets/bootstrap.css">`

Comment: Thanks it was the problem only

Answer (score 1):

Use absolute paths when requiring js and css files `/javascripts/bootstrap.js` and `/stylesheets/bootstrap.css`

Comment: Thanks this was the problem only